# Norm convergence of Fourier coefficient

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

> Let $f\in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ . Show that
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(x+\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)=\hat{f}(0)$$
> in the norm of $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ , where
> $\displaystyle\hat{f}(0)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)dt$ is the zeroth Fourier coefficient.

Since the question makes sense only if we take norm on both sides, therefore I started with following $$\left|\left|\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(x+\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)-\hat{f}(0)\right|\right|_2^2$$ $$=\frac1{n^2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(x+\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)-n\hat{f}(0)\right|^2dx$$ $$\leq\frac1{n^2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left|f\left(x+\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)-\hat{f}(0)\right|^2dx$$ After that I am unable to find a proper justification why that term should go to zero as $n\to\infty$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you should correct it: $f(x+{2\pi k\over n}).$

Comment: Yes , although the question omits $2\pi$ factor , but I think it must be a typo .

Comment: Ok. I will modify the proof accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $f\in L^2(-\pi,\pi)=L^2_{\rm per}(\mathbb{R})$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$ let $f_t(x)=f(x+t)$ . Then
$\widehat{f_t}(m)=e^{itm}\widehat{f}(m)$ .
Thus for  $$g_n(x)={1\over n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f\left (x+{2\pi k\over n}\right)$$ we get
$$\widehat{g}_n(m)=\left ({1\over n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{2\pi ikm/n}\right )\widehat{f}(m)
=\begin{cases} \widehat{f}(m) & m\in n\mathbb{Z} \\
0&  m\notin n\mathbb{Z}
\end{cases}$$

By Parseval identity we obtain
$$ {1\over 2\pi}\|g_n-\widehat{f}(0)\|_2^2= \|\widehat{g}_n-\widehat{f}(0)\delta_0\|_{\ell^2}^2=\sum_{0\neq j=-\infty}^\infty |\widehat{f}(nj)|^2\le \sum_{|k|\ge n}|\widehat{f}(k)|^2\underset{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0.
$$